# bash скрипт по ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

Пытаюсь написать скрипт, которые бы по ssh выполнял на выбор определенные команды т.е. вводим имя компа, вводим цифру соответствуюшую какой то команде, далее через условия выполняем нужную команду.

Проблема:
пишет что не найден процесс такой то, т.е. поиск процесса и grep по нему происходит не на удаленной машине, а на моей. При этом если команду `ps aux | grep 1cv8 |grep "Документы" | awk '{print \$2}'` написать за пределами if то она отрабатывает на удаленной машине как положено.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Введите имя компьютера:"
read ip

echo "1-kill Документы, 2-kill Отчёты"
read y

user="root"
pass="12345"

sshpass -p ${pass} ssh ${user}@${ip} << !

if [ $y -eq 1 ]; then
        kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 1cv8 |grep "Документы" | awk '{print $2}')
elif [ $y -eq 2 ]; then
        kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 1cv8 |grep "Отчеты" | awk '{print $2}')
else
        echo "Ввели не правильное значение"
fi

!
```

Comment: Как вариант попробуйте экранировать знак доллара `\$(ps aux...`

Comment: твой код не срабатывает т.к. на той стороне не выделяется псевдотерминал попробуй переделать вот так **echo 'hostname ' | ssh user@host 'bash -s'** или **ssh user@host 'bash -s' < file.sh**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Авторизация по ключу

Вначале сделайте авторизацию по ключу, то есть без использования пароля.

```
ssh-copy-id root@ваш-удаленный-сервер-1
ssh-copy-id root@ваш-удаленный-сервер-2
...
```

Так проще, и не надо хранить пароли в файле. И обновлять эти пароли.

## 2. Напишите командный скрипт без HEREDOC

В другом ответе предлагают экранировать `$`. Так не удобно писать код. Сделайте отдельный исполняемый файл, который в аргументах принимает все что нужно.

`script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

whoami

echo Первый аргумент команды: $1
```

Такой скрипт также проще отлаживать сразу в виде файла на удаленном сервере без ввода каждый раз команд. Также используйте `set -x` для отладки.

## 3. Напишите скрипт, который копирует и запускает командный скрипт

Скрипт `runner.sh` создает временный файл на удаленной машине, копирует в него командный скрипт `script.sh` и запускает, передавая аргументы:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Введите имя компьютера:"
read ip

echo "1-kill Документы, 2-kill Отчёты"
read y

user="root"

# создаем временный файл на удаленной машине
tmp_file=$(ssh -q ${user}@${ip} mktemp)

# копируем файл script.sh на удаленную машину во временный файл
scp -q $(dirname $(readlink -f $0))/script.sh "$user@$ip:$tmp_file"

# выполняем скрипт
ssh -q $user@$ip "/bin/bash $tmp_file '$y'"
```

Временный файл - каждый раз новый, конфликтов не должно быть. При перезагрузке системы все временные файлы очищаются. При желании, в `runner.sh` добавьте удаление файла.

Comment: а почему надо именно временной файл создавать и в него копировать, а не просто скопировать сам script.sh и далее выполнить его?

Comment: @Tycoon, один файл - принимает параметры и запускает второй скрипт. задачи две. и они поделены на два скрипта. и код стал чище. и отлаживать лучше.

Comment: Через readlink -f $0 мы получим полный путь до файла в котором находится эта команда, далее через dirname в пути уберётся название текущего файла и далее вместо него допишется название второго скрипта /script.sh?

Comment: @Tycoon, да. `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))` - это текущий каталог, где лежат оба скрипта. Ведь скрипт можно запускать из любого места, например скрипт лежит в `~/scripts`, а запускаем его, находясь в `/tmp`: `~/scripts/script.sh`. И тогда если просто прописать путь `scp ./script.sh` - такая конструкция будет искать скрипт в `/tmp/script.sh`, что не верно. Поэтому так мы получаем каталог с выполняемым скриптом и добавляем нужный файл. Как вариант - указать абсолютный путь, или всегда менять рабочий каталог на тот, где скрипт (`cd ~/scripts`). Но это не удобно.

Comment: По вашему варианту всё получилось, всё разобрал и усвоил. Спасибо большое, много нового узнал.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Как вариант, в начале скрипта делать `cd $(dirname $(readlink -f $0))` чтобы потом ссылаться на файлы из этого каталога более просто `scp ./script.sh ...`. Ну и ключик `-q` используется чтобы подавлять сообщение [приветствия motd](https://wiki.it-kb.ru/unix-linux/debian/jessie/configuring-dynamic-motd-in-debian-linux-8-jessie)

Comment: В начале скрипта `cd` — это саморасставленные грабли. Ну и не помешает также вместо огорода использовать что-то типа `PROG_NAME="${0##*/}"
PROG_DIR="${0%/*}"`.

Answer (score 3):

вы используете [heredoc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) для передачи аргументов программе *ssh* (ну, точнее, *sshpass*, которую лучше выкинуть и забыть, освоив аутентификацию по ключу).

внутри *heredoc* **до** передачи его программе осуществляется полноценная обработка кода: подстановка значений переменных, подстановка вывода команд (внутри `$(...)`) и т.п.

чтобы избежать данных подстановок (т.е., передать строки программе «как есть»), можно заэкранировать символ `$`, добавив перед ним обратный слэш.

в вашем случае это требуется в четырёх местах:

```
... \$(...) ... \$2 ...
... \$(...) ... \$2 ...
```

---

можно было бы полностью отключить какую-либо интерпретацию кода внутри *heredoc*, заключив «слово-ограничитель» в кавычки:

```
команда << 'слово'
...
слово
```

но в этом случае не будет подсталено и значение переменной `$y`, что нарушит логику работы того, что вы пишете.

Comment: Так `print`  от `awk` в одинарных кавычках, по идее экранировать их не нужно

Comment: @PotroNik, по идее — не нужно, а на практике получилось, что надо. иначе подставляется значение второго аргумента скрипта. как-нибудь попозже разберусь, отчего так происходит.

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.

Answer (score 0):

А как прикрутить сюда RSA ключик, тк подключение SFTP SSH требует подключение с использованием публичного ключика RSA... Как сделать скрипт копирования файла из локальной папки сервера linux ubuntu в удаленную папку, по ssh sftp, но с использованием ключика? Спасибо!

Comment: Что по подобное? Или есть проще, лучше? - scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub FILENAME USER@SERVER:/home/USER/FILENAME

Comment: Еще момент, может WinSCP можно сделать автоматизацию копирования?

Comment: Поясню. Ключ RSA уже зарегистрирован на удаленном сервере, нам нужно лишь использовать его в команде для аутентификации и передачи файлов из папки А в папку Б. Как правильно написать команду, подойдет ли это? Спасибо! scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub FILENAME USER@SERVER:/home/USER/FILENAME

Comment: Если на удаленной машине установлен ssh key то я обычно копирую так scp /tmp/123.zip user@192.168.243.22:/tmp/ Если вы копируете файлы в локалке, они большие и их много то лучше использовать rsync, он копирувет быстрее чем scp. Если у вас много машин, на которые надо скопировать файлы или сделать любую другу манипуляцию то рекомендую присмотрется к ansible, очень удобная вещь и не сложная, на ютубе есть видеоуроки.

Comment: спасибо! но мне нужно использовать ключик RSA как написать команду? Поясню. Ключ RSA уже зарегистрирован на удаленном сервере, нам нужно лишь использовать его в команде для аутентификации и передачи файлов из папки А в папку Б. Как правильно написать команду, подойдет ли это? Спасибо! scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub FILENAME USER@SERVER:/home/USER/FILENAME

Comment: Не получилось этой командой: scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub FILENAME USER@SERVER:/home/USER/FILENAME

Требует пароль 8-(

Comment: ну при создании rsa ключа пароль указывали? Вот его и надо вводить.

Comment: у вас сервер SFTP на Windows?